# JSoup (Web scraping) returning only four images

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I have the following code which I am using to scrap images from the flipkart website,all is working well but I don't know why it is just retrieving FIRST four images and **not all images present on the web page**.Help me to sort this one

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * Example program to list links from a URL.
 */
public class FlipkartFetcher {
  static String folderPath="C:\\Users\\Nobal\\Desktop\\MyImages";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       // Validate.isTrue(args.length == 1, "usage: supply url to fetch");
        //String url = args[0];
        String url="http://www.flipkart.com/mens-clothing/shirts/formal-shirts/pr?sid=2oq%2Cs9b%2Cmg4%2Cfh5&otracker=nmenu_sub_men_0_Formal+Shirts";
        //print("Fetching %s...", url);

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements divTags=doc.getElementsByClass("pu-visual-section");
        int counter=0;
        for(Element divTag : divTags)
        {
            counter++;
            //System.out.println(image.getElementsByTag("a"));
            Elements aTags=divTag.getElementsByTag("a");
            for(Element aTag : aTags )
            {
                if(aTag.child(0).attr("src").contains(".jp")){
                System.out.println(aTag.child(0).attr("src"));
                getImages(aTag.child(0).attr("src"));
            }
                }

        }

 /*       Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        Elements media = doc.select("[src]");
        Elements imports = doc.select("link[href]");

        print("\nMedia: (%d)", media.size());
        for (Element src : media) {
            if (src.tagName().equals("img"))
                print(" * %s: <%s> %sx%s (%s)",
                        src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"), src.attr("width"), src.attr("height"),
                        trim(src.attr("alt"), 20));
            else
                print(" * %s: <%s>", src.tagName(), src.attr("abs:src"));
        }

        print("\nImports: (%d)", imports.size());
        for (Element link : imports) {
            print(" * %s <%s> (%s)", link.tagName(),link.attr("abs:href"), link.attr("rel"));
        }

        print("\nLinks: (%d)", links.size());
        for (Element link : links) {
            print(" * a: <%s>  (%s)", link.attr("abs:href"), trim(link.text(), 35));
        }*/
    }

    private static void getImages(String src) throws IOException {



        String folder = null;



        //Exctract the name of the image from the src attribute

       int indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");



        if (indexname == src.length()) {

            src = src.substring(1, indexname);

        }



        indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");

        String name = src.substring(indexname, src.length());




        System.out.println(name);



        //Open a URL Stream

        URL url = new URL(src);

        InputStream in = url.openStream();



        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream( folderPath+ name));



        for (int b; (b = in.read()) != -1;) {

            out.write(b);

       }

        out.close();

        in.close();



    }

 /*   private static void print(String msg, Object... args) {
        System.out.println(String.format(msg, args));
    }

    private static String trim(String s, int width) {
        if (s.length() > width)
            return s.substring(0, width-1) + ".";
        else
            return s;
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because some images are not found in the `src` but the `data-src` tag. Adjusted code (Java 8):

```
for (Element divTag : divTags) {
        Elements aTags = divTag.getElementsByTag("a");

        aTags.stream()
                .filter(aTag -> aTag.child(0).attr("data-src").contains(".jp"))
                .forEach(aTag -> {
                    System.out.println(aTag.child(0).attr("data-src"));
                });

        aTags.stream()
                .filter(aTag -> aTag.child(0).attr("src").contains(".jp"))
                .forEach(aTag -> {
                    System.out.println(aTag.child(0).attr("src"));
                });
    }
```